# List of common Monero terms and definitions

Tags: monero-terminology, moneropedia

Monero utilizes many of the same concepts as Bitcoin but has a code-base that looks vastly different. CryptoNote and Monero introduces a lot of new terms that may not be familiar to all Bitcoin users

Is there a comprehensive list of most common Monero terms with there associated definitions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several lists, each of which is community generated and a work in progress. Since Monero technology continues to evolve, there will always be a need to add additional terms, and in some cases depreciate old ones that are no longer used.

This stack has a list of [Monero tags](https://monero.stackexchange.com/tags) that is continually user updated with new and improved definitions

[Moneropedia](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/moneropedia/) on the official Monero website has many important definitions but is in need of more. Community members [are encouraged](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/3lpjq9/i_wanted_to_raise_some_awareness_for_a_task_that/) to build upon the current Moneropedia list.

The [Monero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monero_(cryptocurrency)) and [CryptoNote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptoNote) wikipedia pages are also helpful community generated resources for learning the meaning of Monero terminology.

Comment: Note that if you own or are otherwise invested in Monero, and you edit wikipedia page, you'll need to [declare the conflict of interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Conflict_of_interest#Declaring_an_interest) (; you'll be allowed to edit, but your edits will be watched more closely for bias).